# Angular 2 - can I stay with rc4 forever?

Tags: angular, version, release

I have a pretty built out application using a webpack starter kit and Angular 2.  I am currently on version rc4 of Angular 2 and was wondering if it would be wise/unwise/plausible to stick with rc4 and never update it again?

I ask because the refactoring that I would need to perform to make all of my components work is VERY heavy, considering I would have to make it compatible with the webpack generator and rc5.

I'm honestly thinking that it might be about the same amount of work to switch to react so I don't have to deal with another update...

Any thought/advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to contradict you, but I find it quite hard that updating to RC5 would be the same as moving to React. In fact RC5 is compatible with RC4 code, your components would stay the same and you can slowly migrate your component declarations to modules/module.

I guess you already read the [migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) from RC4 to RC5.

I understand it might be frustrating all these breaking changes, but that's why it's a release candidate, it's not stable and you have to use it at your own risk. If you really need something more stable, then now it's a good time to migrate to React, because RC6 is around the corner and god knows how many features, refactors, changes and breaking changes are coming.

As for staying forever on RC4, RC4 is full of bugs it's not even production ready and eventually you will get a lot of problems down the road, as your app gets bigger. And if you think that migrating now is hard, imagine after the oficial release.

Comment: Do you know the release date for rc 6 ?

Comment: No idea, but my guess would be in time for Angular Connect

Comment: I'd expect RC.6 today. Wednestday is usually when they are releasing. AFAIK they are not working on big changes currently (like modules before RC.5 which could only be released entirely or not at all) only lots of fixes and removal of deprecated API, therefore there should be no need to delay the release.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer didn't know that